# Difference in between mysql_num_rows and mysql_affected_rows

Tags: mysql

I want to know what is the difference in between `mysql_num_rows` and `mysql_affected_rows`.How to know when it should use.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.Examples are most welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows` for **`SELECT`** queries while `mysql_affected_rows` for **`UPDATE`** and **`DELETE`** queries.

- `mysql_num_rows` tells you how many records were returned from a `SELECT` query
- `mysql_affected_rows` tells you how many rows were `UPDATE`ed or `DELETE`ed

Answer (score 1):

I would only add that, mysqli_num_rows requires for a atribute the result set variable, while mysqli_affected_rows requires for a atribute the database connection variable. That is important difference.

Answer (score 0):

With the `SELECT` query, `mysqli_affected_rows` will work the same way as `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: Yeah. I found this info on the official php web site. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)